# Easiest way to merge C Dlls. Have Source

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, dll

I'm working with [pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net). It comes in 2 dlls. `sphinxbase.dll` and `pocketsphinx.dll`. `pocketsphinx.dll` calls on functions in `sphinxbase.dll`. I'm going to be calling functions in both. I'd like to know the easiest way to merge both source files into producing a single dll.

I've tried this before but I run into the problem of pocketsphinx using sphinxbase leading to a warning/error about importing functions I'm trying to export.

What's the common solution to get around this?
Should I remove the dllexport tags from sphinbase and then wrap those functions inside other functions that I then export?

Example

```
//inside sphinxbase
SPHINXBASE_DLL_EXPORT
void sphinxbasefunc();


//inside pocketsphinx
POCKETSPHINX_DLL_EXPORT
char* decode(ps_decoder_t decoder)
{
  ...
  sphinxbasefunc();
  ...
}
```

Then I would remove the SPHINXBASE_DLL_EXPORT macro and create a wrapper that I would then export.

```
//inside sphinxbase
void sphinxbasefunc();

WRAPPER_DLL_EXPORT
void sphinxbasefunc_wrapper() { sphinxbasefunc(); }
```

This solution I think is naive on my own part though. Theres dozens of functions I would need to wrap if I took this route.

Comment: I'm working in Unity and Unity has a bug where it will only load a single dll. The common workaround is to put the dependent dlls in a separate location however, then you don't have access to the dependent dlls via scripts.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. (Ugly bug, though.) Thanks for explaining. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to realize is like an exe, a dll is just a collection of one or more object files bound into a package.  Combining object files into dlls/exes is the linker's job.  If you want to combine your two dlls into one, combine the object files that make up your two dlls into one dll.  When you do that your references will no longer be to dlls, but directly to the objects themselves (source code changes will be required, but mostly this is removing dllimports), so it should be a much more direct process (include the header, make sure the object is included in the link).  You only need to export those functions required by consumers of the final dll.  Basically put the source for both dlls into one project.  I'm assuming of course that you have the source for these dlls (which is how it appears from the url given).  If you end up with circular dependencies you may have to create some forward declarations or additional header files to keep the compiler happy.

Comment: I think I understand but I'm not sure if it'll work. You're telling me to create object files. Then create a new header to those object file that has all my dllexports? Will this allow me to export functions that are used in the object files themselves? Can this work with a static lib as well instead of a bunch of object files?

Comment: It should work, just treat your imports as direct references (because they are no longer being imported).  The down side to this is that when the library changes you will need to recompile (you can't just drop a new dll in place), but anything that physically merges dlls will lead to the same issue.